# Induced surface charge for a conductor within two parallel plates that carry different charges ($+Q$ and $-2Q$)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, gauss-law

This is my first question and appreciate all your help.

**An infinitely wide conductor is parallel to two infinitely wide planes with surface charge density $-2$ and $+$ respectively.**

**How to find the induced charge density on both sides of the conductor?**

I know the electric field generated by a charged plate with surface density  is

=/2. While for a charged conductor the electric field is

=/.

But I'm not sure how to deal with the unbalanced charges on both sides of the conductor. I think after all the induced charges should add up to zero? So the induced charge densities can NOT be +2 and - for the up and down side of the conductor?

[this question](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-we-put-a-conductor-between-the-plates-of-a-capacitor) is the case when both planes have equal but opposite charges, and in this case the set-up could be seen as two capacitor in parallel.

But I still do not know how to deal with the unbalanced cases. And maybe I'm not using the right keywords because I cannot find relevant questions online.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can "divide" the charges between two sides of the plates and using formula $E = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ find electric field on every region. The constraint on the system is that $E$ must be zero inside the plates.